# laravel 4 page is not working for a newbie

Tags: laravel-4

I am totally new for laravel and trying to create a view for about us page.
But it is not working right when I am setting this in a route file.

Here is my HomeController functions:

```
public function showWelcome()
{
    return View::make('hello');
}

public function showAboutus()
{
    return View::make('about.about');
}
```

And here is the routes file:

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
Route::get('about', 'HomeController@showWelcome');
```

Comment: *"it is not working"* doesn't describe the problem too well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.... 'HomeController@showWelcome' ...
```

should be

```
.... 'HomeController@showAboutus' ...
```

On the About route.

Plus the second parameter is an array so use

```
Route::get('/', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showWelcome'));

Route::get('about', array('uses' => 'HomeController@showAboutus'));
```